# SQL SERVER : how to use field names in parameters of a table function inside a JOIN clause?

Tags: sql-server

Using a field name in a parameter of a table function inside a JOIN clause seems to be not allowed.

select * from MyTable left join MyFunction(MyTable.MyField) xxx on 1=1 result in a Msg 207 "invalid field name"

For example, MyFunction('XXX') returns 3 lines, so I would like to obtain 3 times the same line of MyTable when I do this :
insert into MyTable(MyField) values ('XXX')
select * from MyTable left join MyFunction(MyTable.MyField) xxx on 1=1

Here is an example of code :

```
create function MyFunction(@param1 varchar(3))
returns @result table (MyResult varchar(3))
as
begin
  if (@param1='XXX')
  begin
    insert @result values ('AAA')
    insert @result values ('BBB')
    insert @result values ('CCC')
  end
  else
  begin
    insert @result values ('ZZZ')
  end
 return
end

create table MyTable (MyField varchar(3))
insert into MyTable values ('ABC')
insert into MyTable values ('XXX')
```

The result I expect with `select * from MyTable left join MyFunction(MyField) on 1=1 is`
woud be :

```
XXX
XXX
XXX
ABC
```

instead of what I obtain :

```
Msg 207, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 122
Nom de colonne non valide : 'MyField'.
```

Thanks in advance for any idea !

Comment: `left join MyFunction(MyField) on 1=1`? Why? When will `1` ever not equal `1`, so why is it `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: did not knew that, it works fine, thx !

Answer (score 1):

To pass a column reference to a function, use the [APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator

> left_table_source { CROSS | OUTER } APPLY right_table_source Specifies
>   that the right_table_source of the APPLY operator is evaluated against
>   every row of the left_table_source. This functionality is useful when
>   the right_table_source contains a table-valued function that takes
>   column values from the left_table_source as one of its arguments.

So something like:

```
select * from MyTable 
cross apply dbo.MyFunction(MyField)
```